# BSD licensing - what do I put in the organisation tag, if I'm the sole programmer?

Tags: licensing

Point three for example:

> - Neither the name of the ORGANIZATION nor the names of its contributors may
>     be used to endorse or promote products
>     derived from this software without
>     specific prior written
>     permission.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: "Huh? I... I don't know that" and is hurled off the bridge by their own magic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using the [MIT License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)  as an alternative? It seems (to my eyes) to say about the same thing, but without the organization section.

When I used the BSD license I just reworded it so that it didn't mention organization.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm pretty clueless to this licensing issue so thanks. One question though, the BSD license says you must acknowledge the creator. The MIT license does not. Is there something following this format?

Comment: @Dockers - the modified version of MIT used by XFree86 has an acknowledgment clause. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License)